# SSH error while connecting to host, using a Identity file in a custom directory: ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in environment

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ssh, git

The question is about issues faced while using ssh to connect to a remote host (mainly, git), using a custom config (like port, identify file, .ssh folder location, etc).

**Configuration details:**
**Laptop:** `Dell XPS 15z (L511Z)`
**OS:** `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal)`
**DE:** `xubuntu-desktop`, `xfce`
**Display Manager:** `lightdm`
**Input method:** `xim`

**GIT version:** `git version 2.25.1`
**SSH Version:** `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

I have setup my `ssh` as below:

1. `sudo apt-get install ssh`
2. `sudo apt-get install  molly-guard monkeysphere ssh-askpass` (These packages were recommended by `apt`).
3. I also installed both `openssh-client` and the `openssh-server` - based on suggestions from stackexchange.
4. Gave a strong passphrase.
5. Shared my public key with the client & they've shared their git repository connect links (which I use to connect to their server repository, using ssh/git commands).
6. Changed the default `Port: 22`, to a diff. `Port: xx`.
7. Changed the default ssh folder location from `~/.ssh` to `/xxxx/xxxx.ssh`.
8. Changed the default `known_hosts` file location from `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/known_hosts` to `/xxxx/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts`.
9. Moved all files/config related to ssh, to a custom directory.
   **Files like:** `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`, `known_hosts` & `authorized_keys`. (did this, so that I don't have to re-configure everything, whenever I re-install my OS).
10. Removed the `~/.ssh` folder (Note that this folder is nowhere there now. May be, that's an issue).
11. Allowed `ssh` via my router & with `ufw`.

Now, whenever I do `ssh user@hostIP`, it asks for the `passphrase` 3 times & says unable to connect or connection timout. So, to debug, I ran

`ssh -vi <path_to_custom_identityfile> username@hostIP`

and got the below output:

```
$ ssh -vi /xxxx/xxxx/id_rsa_xx git@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /xxxx/xxxx/id_rsa_xxx type 0
debug1: identity file /xxxx/xxxx/id_rsa_xxx-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:AQKsBukNwZoDJEEUZt/XTj1AUSeeiFKw5W3QBxcFObw
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /xxxx/xxxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/id_rsa_xxx RSA SHA256:Bh3pQ+E3Q70wjZ7qfuLkzdT7Hc4ItLHsR/C+KGeqzRM explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/id_rsa_xxx RSA SHA256:Bh3pQ+E3Q70wjZ7qfuLkzdT7Hc4ItLHsR/C+KGeqzRM explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/id_rsa_xxx RSA SHA256:Bh3pQ+E3Q70wjZ7qfuLkzdT7Hc4ItLHsR/C+KGeqzRM explicit
Enter passphrase for key '/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxx/id_rsa_xxx': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
**debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: PTY allocation disabled.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in environment.**
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
Transferred: sent 3896, received 3516 bytes, in 0.9 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4523.6, received 4082.4
debug1: Exit status 1
```

**Note:** I have highlighted the lines that I felt suspicious, in the above output.

I have also done some troubleshooting changes (suggestions from `stackoverflow`, `askubuntu`, `serverfault`,etc.
Some of them are:

1. Un-mount and re-mount the `/dev/pts`.

   - I wasn't able to re-mount it. Note: It is mentioned this step is not required in systems using `systemd` (which mine is using).
2. Modified ssh configs like,
   `ForwardX11Trusted`, `PasswordAuthentication`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`, `IdentityFile`, `IdentitiesOnly`, `UserKnownHostsFile`, `X11Forwarding`, `AllowTcpForwarding`, `PermitTTY`, etc.

I think some config changes like `X11Forwarding`, `PasswordAuthentication`, `IdentityFile` had some response. Not sure about other configs though. Not sure if they're required (or) they're harmful to my system, also.

> **Strangely, people (esp. the account owners of the git server, that I'm trying to connect) mentioned that I should not use a passphrase & it might cause issues. They insist that all others who have been given access, faced no issues on doing all/any operations using git - the only diff. being I'm using a passphrase.  I'm curious to know whether this is true & if yes,
> why/how.**

Below is the content of my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   PasswordAuthentication no
#   PermitEmptyPasswords no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h

    **Port xxxx
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking ask
    IdentityFile=/xxxx/xxxx/id_rsa
    ##Added based on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494483/specifying-an-identityfile-with-ssh
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    UserKnownHostsFile=/xxxx/xxxx/known_hosts
        X11Forwarding yes
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    PermitTTY yes
    
    #Added to keep the ssh connection to host's Server alive, for more time.
    #Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/283129/why-do-consoles-sometimes-hang-forever-when-ssh-connection-breaks
    ServerAliveInterval 15
    ServerAliveCountMax 3**
```

Below is the content of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

**#Override values - as running ssh verbose debug, stated these as disabled.
    X11Forwarding yes
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    PermitTTY yes**

**# Copied from /etc/ssh/ssh_config file, to ensure that the settings persist - even if the system uses this (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) file instead.
# copied on 2022-03-23_15:54 hrs. 
    Port xx
    # SendEnv LANG LC_*
    # HashKnownHosts yes
    # GSSAPIAuthentication no
    #PasswordAuthentication no
    #PermitEmptyPasswords no
    #RSAAuthentication yes
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    # StrictHostKeyChecking ask
    # IdentityFile=/xxxx/xxxx/id_rsa
    # UserKnownHostsFile=/xxxx/xxxx/known_hosts
    
    #Added to keep the ssh connection to client's server alive, for more time.
    #Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/283129/why-do-consoles-sometimes-hang-forever-when-ssh-connection-breaks
    # ServerAliveInterval 15
    # ServerAliveCountMax 3**
```

Below are the files under `/etc/ssh` folder:

```
$ sudo ls /etc/ssh
moduli      ssh_config.d  sshd_config.d       ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub  ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_config  sshd_config   ssh_host_ecdsa_key  ssh_host_ed25519_key    ssh_host_rsa_key      ssh_import_id
```

As mentioned in the beginning, there's no `~/.ssh/` folder.

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
<blank here>
```

(However, a known_hosts file gets created whenever I run the `ssh` command. Not sure whether to leave it as it is, or to remove it every time. Don't know if I can/should avoid it getting created, either).

**File permissions:**

I have modified the file permissions for both ssh folder & files like `IdentityFile`, `known_hosts`, `authorized_keys` under the custom path.

1. `/etc/ssh` folder permission.
   [image: /etc/ssh folder permission.]
2. Permissions on files under `/etc/ssh`:
   [image: Permissions on files under /etc/ssh.]
3. Permissions for files like, `IdentityFile`, `known_hosts`, `authorized_keys`, etc, under the custom path/directory:
   [image: Permissions for files like, IdentityFile, known_hosts, authorized_keys, etc, under the custom path/directory.]
4. Permission for the custom directory holding the above files:
   [image: Permission for the custom directory holding the above files]

I'm almost certain that more info would be of help to zero-in on the issue.
Please let me know & I'll share the required info asap.

It would also be of great help, if you could share some quality KB/sites on this topic.
(not just on the how-to's, but also on why/what parts too).

Thank you!

**Edit (03-04-2022):**

Following [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)'s suggestion, I tried to use `git pull` instead of `ssh` & got this output.
[image: Permission denied for git pull command]

Strangely though, `git status` doesn't throw any error.
[image: No error when git status command is used.]

Running `git status` inside the project folder that I've cloned earlier, gives this:

[image: git status inside cloned project folder]

Comment: `debug1: Remote: Forced command.` suggests that you've done everything you can from your side, but the remote side doesn't permit shell access (perhaps it just allows git **over** ssh) - see for example [SSH and GitHub](https://devopshomelab.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/ssh-and-github/). FWIW nothing in *your* sshd_config should affect connections *from* your computer.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. I tried using `git` instead of `ssh`. Got error when I tried `git pull`, but no error on using `git status`. Would that mean I have a read-only permission on the repo? They insist that all others who have been given access, faced no issues on doing all operations using `ssh/git` - the only diff. being I'm using a passphrase. However, I'm really am not sure how using a passphrase would make a difference. After all, it's just another security option.

Comment: Hmm... I suspect `git status` only looks at the local working tree. I also can't see how the passphrase would make a difference - afaik it only wraps the *private* key (which stays on the client side), the remote server should neither know nor care. However if they insist that's the issue, you can always remove the passphrase (i.e. set an empty one) using `ssh-keygen -p`. Good luck!